# Make copy of XML page using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, xml

I'm trying to use Javascript to access data from http://www.bart.gov/dev/eta/bart_eta.xml , however, I found out that I cannot do that unless I have a copy of that page on my server. How can I make a proxy page on my server that is an exact copy of http://www.bart.gov/dev/eta/bart_eta.xml ? I have already tried simplexml_load_file and file_get_contents, however both functions do not give me the XML format, they give me something like `object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (2) { ["channel"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (6) { ["title"]=> string(23) "BART Real Time ETA Feed" ["link"]=> string(50) "http://www.bart.gov/schedules/developers/etas.aspx" ["description"]=> string(127) "Real time estimated arrivals for Bay Area Rapid Transit. Use subject to terms at http://www.bart.gov/dev/schedules/license.htm" ["copyright"]=> string(86) "Copyright (C) 2012 San Francisco Bay Area Rapid Transit District. All rights reserved." ["date"]=> string(10) "07/01/2012" ["time"]=> string(15) "02:52:39 PM PDT" } ["station"]=> array(44) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (5) { ["name"]=> string(12)   ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the content type first.

Put the following file on your server `bart_eta_proxy.php` for example, and try to access it.

```
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
echo file_get_contents('http://www.bart.gov/dev/eta/bart_eta.xml');
```

and here you go, it's working:
[image]

Comment: This still outputs `BART Real Time ETA Feedhttp://www.bart.gov/schedules/developers/etas.aspxReal time estimated arrivals for Bay Area Rapid Transit. Use subject to terms at http://www.bart.gov/dev/schedules/license.htmCopyright (C) 2012 San Francisco Bay Area Rapid Transit District. All rights reserved.07/01/201203:09:01 PM PDTLake MerrittLAKE07/01/201203:09:01 PM PDTDaly City6 min, 26 min, 46 minDublin/Pleasanton15 min, 31 min, 51 minFremont17 min, 37 min, 57 minRichmond19 min, 39 min, 59 minFruitvaleFTVL07/01/201203:09:01 ` and not in XML format.

Comment: @user1261817, well same exact code is working with me. Updated my answer and posted a pic.

Comment: I used the code `<?
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
echo file_get_contents('http://www.bart.gov/dev/eta/bart_eta.xml');
?>` but it still outputs the same thing.

Comment: Where are you viewing the output? Can you provide piece of the raw output? (at least the first parts of a browser’s "View Source")

Comment: I tested your code here: http://danielhonline.com/BART/bart.php

My code is `<html>

<?

header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");

echo file_get_contents('http://www.bart.gov/dev/eta/bart_eta.xml');

?>

</html>`

Comment: @user1261817, Right click -> View source.. you'll see that you'll hosting company is adding an analytics script which is breaking the XML format. (and for the love of god remove the `<html>` tags). Google the following "disable analytics `your hosting company's name`"

Answer (score 0):

You can actually access information from a remote domain through Javascript: just use AJAX to do a request to that site.

A very simple example, using jquery:

```
function handlePage(xml)
{ /* Do something with that XML-page. */ }

$.ajax('http://www.bart.gov/dev/eta/bart_eta.xml').success(handlePage);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know jquery.

Comment: I barely know jQuery myself, but when I need to know how to do something I simply look it up. Using jQuery is a lot simpler than using the standard DOM function and, more importantly, portable over different browsers. Learning how jQuery and its $-operator basically work shouldn't take more than about half an hour; I can really recommend it.

Answer (score -1):

Once you have all the data stored in variable, why don't you just loop through all the data and store it in file? After that you can proceed as you want.

Comment: Are there any examples? Thanks.